# "Command Error Status: Unsupported" Error on QEMU & OVMF & Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, qemu, uefi, edk2

I’m trying to compile a (lightweight) Linux kernel and start it on QEMU (and OVMF).

There is the [build-and-run script](https://gist.github.com/kuraga/4deec061ab859f630bdab2005b388276).

In OVMF’s EFI Internal Shell, on

```
$ fs0:\vmlinuz-6.2.1
```

I get:

```
Command Error Status: Unsupported
```

Calculate Linux 23 (Gentoo-based)
QEMU 7.2.0, OVMF edk2-stable202202

It does start via `-kernel` QEMU's option.

Help, please? Thanks!

Comment: something doesn't match. Are your qemu, system, efi, and kernel all 64 bit? All Intel architecture?

Comment: In my experience that message often means that the file isn't in the proper executable format.

Comment: @stark, Yes. It does start via `-kernel` QEMU's option.

Comment: @prl, it must mean. But where's the error?

Comment: I get the same issue. Was never able to find a solution and gave up at os dev.